# Creating a scratch card in EaselJS

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, easeljs

I've been trying to develop a scratch card in EaselJS.
So far, I've managed to get a Shape instance above a Bitmap one and enabled erasing it with click and drag events, so the image below becomes visible.

I've used the `updateCache()` with the `compositeOperation` approach and it was easy enough, but here is my issue:

How can I find out how much the user has already erased from the Shape instance, so I can setup a callback function when, say, 90% of the image below is visible?

Here is a functioning example of what I'm pursuing: http://codecanyon.net/item/html5-scratch-card/full_screen_preview/8721110?ref=jqueryrain&ref=jqueryrain&clickthrough_id=471288428&redirect_back=true

This is my code so far:

```
function Lottery(stageId) {
    this.Stage_constructor(stageId);

    var self = this;

    var isDrawing = false;
    var x, y;

    this.autoClear = true;      
    this.enableMouseOver();

    self.on("stagemousedown", startDrawing);
    self.on("stagemouseup", stopDrawing);
    self.on("stagemousemove", draw);

    var rectWidth = self.canvas.width;
    var rectHeight = self.canvas.height;

    // Image
    var background = new createjs.Bitmap("http://www.taxjusticeblog.org/lottery.jpg");
    self.addChild(background);

    // Layer above image
    var overlay = new createjs.Shape();
    overlay.graphics
        .f("#55BB55")
        .r(0, 0, rectWidth, rectHeight);
    self.addChild(overlay);
    overlay.cache(0, 0, self.canvas.width, self.canvas.height);

    // Cursor
    self.brush = new createjs.Shape();
    self.brush.graphics
        .f("#DD1111")
        .dc(0, 0, 5);
    self.brush.cache(-10, -10, 25, 25);
    self.cursor = "none";

    self.addChild(self.brush);

    function startDrawing(evt) {
        x = evt.stageX-0.001;
        y = evt.stageY-0.001;
        isDrawing = true;
        draw(evt);
    };

    function stopDrawing() {
        isDrawing = false;
    };

    function draw(evt) {

        self.brush.x = self.mouseX;
        self.brush.y = self.mouseY;

        if (!isDrawing) {
            self.update();
            return;
        }

        overlay.graphics.clear();

        // Eraser line
        overlay.graphics
            .ss(15, 1)
            .s("rgba(30,30,30,1)")
            .mt(x, y)
            .lt(evt.stageX, evt.stageY);

        overlay.updateCache("destination-out");

        x = evt.stageX;
        y = evt.stageY;

        self.update();

        $rootScope.$broadcast("LotteryChangeEvent");
    };
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a tricky one, regardless of the language. The naive solution would simply be to track the length of the paths the user "draws" within the active area, and then reveal when they scratch long enough. That's obviously not very accurate, but is fairly simple and might be good enough.

The more accurate approach would be to get the pixel data of the `cacheCanvas`, then check the alpha value of each pixel to get an idea of how many pixels are transparent (have low alpha). You could optimize this significantly by only checking every N pixel (ex. every 5th pixel in every 5th row would run 25X faster).

Comment: Thanks for the very quick answer, gskinner. (:

The second approach seems to be a good idea, but I have a question: when I "erase" from the shape using the `destination-out` option, are the points from the `Shape` object altered or just the alpha values of the pixels? (What I really mean is can I just implement the analysis of the `cacheCanvas` as you mentioned without altering the process I already have, or should I change it?)

Comment: From the looks of it, you should be good to just analyse the cacheCanvas as it is already.

Comment: Right, I'll give it a go. Thanks very much!